# Async Function Within Jquery $(Document).Ready Not Awaiting (JQuery 1.11.2)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

When attempting to await an immediately executed async function inside $(Document).Ready, the result is not awaited:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var outcomeNameStrings = (async () => {
        let namesObj = await getOutcomeNameStrings();
        return namesObj;
    })();
    console.log(outcomeNameStrings);
    . . . //other code
    debugger; //value is a promise still
}
```

getOutcomeNameStrings creates an HTTP Get call to the server to retrieve a JSON object. This is need before all elements are loaded into the page (i.e. I don't think I can use Window Load). Implementation below:

```
async function getOutcomeNameStrings() {
    return $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Outcomes/GetOutcomeNameStrings",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

The value logged into the Console and at debugger line is a Promise and not the JSON object. I've also tried .then callback functions but this doesn't seem to work either.

The Jquery version is 1.11.2 and is used within a .NET Framework 4.7.2 MVC project. getOutcomeNameStrings hits a GET endpoint method in a controller.

If any more details are required to solve this, I am happy to provide them, thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe use the latest version of jQuery? Version 1.11.2 is *obsolete*, **obsolete** and ***obsolete***.

Comment: I certainly agree, but won't I have to worry about code written for this version (1.11.2) causing errors when switched over to the latest version?
I unfortunately was not part of the decision to start the project using this very deprecated version of JQuery

Comment: Well, I just advised you to update jQuery. New versions are always better. Though I'm not sure it helps.